# z-index Not Working with Absolute Position

Tags: html, css

If you take a look at my test website [here](http://www.hosting-mate.com/marinebuoysaustralia/) you will see that the "Scroll Down" button is overlapping all my content, no matter what z-index I input. Is there a way to fix this issue? I realize that my position is `absolute` and that is most likely the issue, but if I state it as `relative` it is no longer set at the bottom of my page.

```css
#scroll-down {
  height: 53px;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
#scroll-down:hover {
  color: #bae9ff;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-wrap">

  <div class="background-image img-home">

    <div class="text">Welcome!</div>

    <a id="scroll-down noselect">
      <div id="scroll-down">Scroll Down
        <br />
        <object class="scroll-down-img" height="33" width="50"></object>
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>
```

Comment: You want to hide the scroll-down div on scroll?

Comment: Well, I would just prefer it to slip behind the main menu/logo bar (position: fixed)

Comment: Do one thing add z-index:999 to these class .menu-center and .bar-bg-center. It will solve your problem.

Comment: @Jesse check my solution.

Comment: Tried, and failed :(

Comment: @Jesse by this your scroll down will be behind the header and menu, is that you want right?

Comment: Yes that is, however I have tested it and it did not work :/

Comment: .header z-index is set to 1000 already, and that includes ALL the menu and logo stuff

Comment: @Jesse in .top-bar add z-index:999 thats it and see

Comment: Leo, you are a legend! Type it up as an answer so I can mark it as correct please :)

Comment: @Jesse  you can try evilReko's solution too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to push your scroll div under the header then use z-index:999 in .top-bar class so top-bar will come above the scroll bar text and you are done.

```
.top-bar {
 z-index:999;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`z-index` becomes effective only for elements that have attribute `position` with value `absolute` or `fixed` or `relative`. Elements with `position: static` (which is the default for all elements) will not be affected by the `z-index`.

Easiest way in your case, add `position: relative` to .header, so your header tag becomes like this:

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: relative;/* this will fix it */
}
```

Comment: I like your solution better then me.. :)

Answer (score -1):

The problem you have is with "Object" tag. Tags like OBJECT, EMBED,FRAME (and SELECT in some previous browser versions) are rendered as part of window model and does not respect z-index. The classic approach is to put the top content in iframe. In your case I can not understand why you need Object tag for simple button. Just change it with image.